# What's exploding all the time?

Tags: space-engineers

I'm playing my fourth survival game on the Earthlike start as I learn to play this game.  Now and again I've heard a distant explosion.

For my first two games, I assumed these were unannounced meteors, since I was playing with meteors on, and I noticed the "Meteor Storm Incoming" alert was buggy.

Except now I'm playing with meteors off, and I'm still hearing it.  Moreover, I have now witnesses the explosions twice (my current base is atop a a hill with excellent viewshed over the surrounding terrain). Once I caught the residual smoke from the explosion, and just this morning the whole thing - fireball and all - erupted in front of me, probably about 750m-1.5km distant. (There's no distancing laser, so I can't be certain).

These explosions leave no craters in the voxel material as would a crash, so I don't think they're unmarked "unknown signals" meeting unfortunate ends... but I can't imagine what else these could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a fair bit of science on the matter, I have concluded that these are indeed Unknown Signals reaching the end of their timer. Not all Unknown Signals broadcast to you, personally, even in single player, but all of them have a 15m timer until they go boom.